# Wordpress hook to modify email body before it gets sent

Tags: wordpress, email, hook

The scenario: I need to remove some unwanted content from email that gets sent in Wordpress email messages. Basically a preg_replace that needs to happen in the email body before it gets sent to the Wordpress user.

I went through the list of Wordpress hooks and couldn't find a hook for this. Is there another way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The filter you're looking for is `wp_mail`

You could perform a `preg_replace` on the contents like this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'my_replace_mail' );
function my_replace_mail( $args ) {
    if(isset($args['message']) && !empty($args['message'])) {
         $args['message'] = preg_replace("/foo/", "bar", $args['message']);
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Documentation here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does this work on functions.php of a child theme? I tried on my installation and it didn't work.